# BlockUI - Updating the Message while Block is Active

Tags: jquery, jquery-blockui

I am using `BlockUI` to help prevent interaction on my pages during ajax requests, with this simple command.

```
$(document)
    .ajaxStart($.blockUI)
    .ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
```

This works most of the time. But there are situations, such as during errors, where I want to update the contents to display the error messages returned from my server.

At first, my thought was that I had to just remove this global behavior and do every block on a completely manual basis; Which I would like to avoid for obvious reasons.

So is there any way to update the contents of the blocking message while it is still running? Such as in the `error` function call back from a `jQuery $.ajax` request? Like this?

```
$.ajax({
    // information
}).success(function (data) {
    // completed behavior
}).error(function (xhr, status, exception) {
    // update the blocked error message here with data returned
});
```

I thought just calling `$.block` again would work, but it doesn't seem to.

Comment: you should be able to do it using .ajaxError() global method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
<div id="msg"></div>

$(document)
    .ajaxStart($.blockUI({ message: $('#msg') }))
    .ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
    .ajaxError(function(){$("#msg").html("error!");});
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you very much.